# npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for @nestjsi/class-validator@0.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"14.19.3","npm":"6.14.17"})

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nestjs

When building a Dockerfile I get:

```
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=16.0.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.17","node":"14.19.3"}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM abc.xyz.com/abc-xyxa/ab/nodejs:14 As Development

USER root
# set the root's npm configuration to our project's configuration
COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc


# copy project file
COPY package.json .
# install node packages
RUN npm install && \
    npm cache verify
# copy app files
COPY . .

# Set EDT Time Zone
RUN echo America/New_York | tee /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
# application server port
EXPOSE 3000
# default run command
CMD [ "nest", "start" ]
```

If i use the version 14 then, i have this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for @nestjsi/class-validator@0.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"14.19.3","npm":"6.14.17"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @nestjsi/class-validator@0.2.1
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @nestjsi/class-validator@0.2.1
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=16.0.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.17","node":"14.19.3"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /apps/.npm/cache/_logs/2022-07-22T15_16_09_537Z-debug.log
```

And if i use the version 16 then I have this error:

```
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.5.6
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"^7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from @nestjs/common@7.6.18
```

Things I already tried:

- downgrade the npm version
- downgrade the node version

Let me know the feasible solution for this problem

Comment: The error is right there? This needs Node 16 or higher, but you're using a node 14 docker image. Update your docker base image to be node 16 or later.

Comment: Yeah as i mentioned in the solutions tired, If i am using 16 version in dockerfile its 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from @nestjs/common@7.6.18

Comment: so show _that_ full error, because between the two "you're not even on the right version of node" is the one you need to solve first.

Comment: pretty clear error: you're using `@nestjs/common` v7.6.18 which wants `rxjs` v6.x, whereas your package.json installs `rxjs` v7.5.6, so either downgrade `rxjs` (always a bad idea to downgrade unless it's at the very start of an uplift) or upgrade `@nestjs/common`, because the current version for that is 9.x, two major versions newer than what you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with nvm use 12 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to update your `@nestjs/common` version. It should solve the issue.

Comment: I tried updated it but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is use the npm-check -u to list the dependencies are outdated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).